# How to only read R and G components from the fragment shader output?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I am using offscreen rendering to texture for a simple GPU calculation. I am using

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, texSize, texSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

to allocate storage for the texture and

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, texSize, texSize, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

to read out the computed data. The problem is that the output from the fragment shader I am interested in is only `vec2`, so the first two slots of the color attachment are populated and the other two are garbage. I then need to post-process `data` to only take two out of each four `float`s, which takes needless cycles and storage.

If it was one value, I'd use `GL_RED`, if it was three, I'd use `GL_RGB` in my `glReadPixels`. But I couldn't find a format that would read two values. I'm only using `GL_RGBA` for convenience as it seems more natural to take 2 floats out of 2×2 than out of 3.

Is there another way which would read all the resulting `vec2` tightly packed? I thought of reading RED only, somehow convincing OpenGL to skip four bytes after each value, and then reading GREEN only into the same array to fill in the gaps. To this end I tried to study about `glPixelStore` but it does not seem to be for this purpose. Is this, or any other way, even possible?

Comment: There is `GL_RG32F`, maybe it helps

Comment: @geza: No, that's an internal format, not a pixel transfer format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read the RG components of the image, you use a transfer format of `GL_RG` in your `glReadPixels` command.

However, that's going to be a slow read *unless* your image also only stores 2 channels. So your image's internal format should be `GL_RG32F`.

Comment: Is this an undocumented feature? I can't see `GL_RG` mentioned among the accepted values of [glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml).

Comment: @TheVee: Define "undocumented". It's documented in the actual *standard*; those pages are not the normative documentation. Sometimes, they get things wrong. That page doesn't even list the `_INTEGER` formats.

Comment: Indeed, good catch. I would have thought that documentation at www.khronos.org is complete. This works nicely.